# How can I standardize a sample to fixed skewness and kurtosis?

Tags: normalization, standardization, skewness, moments, kurtosis

Standardizing a sample of a random variable to mean 0 and standard deviation 1 are common practice. However, I would like to also standardize its skewness to 0 and its kurtosis to 3, but preserve higher order statistics. I'm aware of quantile normalization, which would allow me to make the sample look Gaussian, but then I would lose higher order statistics.

Comment: I don't know a way of doing what you want and fear that your aims are contradictory. You can map to standard normal deviates, or linear scalings thereof, but doing that destroys all information in higher moments. Wanting your distribution to mimic a Gaussian and to remain non-Gaussian are different games.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this is not possible. But I'm thinking there should be some nonlinear transformation that sets the higher moments to some desired value. It's not like the distribution will be actually a Gaussian afterwards, it will has higher order moments that are free.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "standardize." You have already used up all possibility of linear transformation when you recenter and rescale the variable.  In what manner do you wish to alter it further?  *It can't be with a linear transformation!*

Comment: Ideally, I would like to nonlinearly transform the variable such that its first 4 moments are fixed to the desired values and all higher (normalized) moments remain at the same as the original data. Maybe that's not possible? I don't quite understand why the question was closed.

Comment: I closed the question out of concern it would garner confusing or inappropriate answers.  After you have edited it to clarify what you are looking for, it might be clear enough to answer.  The issue with your comment is that there are too many possible solutions because "nonlinearly transform" covers a lot of ground.  It would help us to know why you want to make this transformation.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question to me. I also don't know why it was closed. As a mathematical question, it is reasonably well posed. Does such a transformation even exist, such that higher order moments are preserved? What an interesting question!

Comment: @BigBendRegion In this generality the question is almost without content, because all you have to do is find a set of data of the same size with the desired values of the moments and use that to define a mapping.  That would have little, if any, statistical meaning.

Comment: I was assuming that a probability distribution is unique determined by all its moments (0 to infinity), so changing the first four moments and keeping all higher moments fixed would have a unique answer. But I just saw that this is only true for distributions on bounded intervals, so there would likely be multiple solutions there. Maybe the solution on bounded intervals works in both cases, if there even exists a closed form for the transformation.